# Error installing a crate via cargo: specified package has no binaries

Tags: installation, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm trying to install a Rust crate on my system (Arch Linux) using Cargo. I can search for crates and find what I need, for example:

```
 $ cargo search curl | head -n3
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
curl (0.3.0)             Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests
curl-sys (0.2.0)         Native bindings to the libcurl library
```

When I try to install it, I get the following error:

```
 $ cargo install curl
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
error: specified package has no binaries
```

What does this mean? Do I have to build it from source first? What's the point of Cargo if it does not install it in the first place?

```
 $ uname -a
Linux 4.6.1-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 2 15:46:17 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 $ rustc --version
rustc 1.9.0
 $ cargo --version
cargo 0.10.0 (10ddd7d 2016-04-08)
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`cargo install` is used to install binary packages that happen to be distributed through crates.io.

If you want to use a crate as a dependency, add it to your `Cargo.toml`.

Read [the Rust getting started guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-02-hello-world.html#hello-cargo) and [the Cargo getting started guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/first-steps.html) for further information. In short:

```
cargo new my_project
cd my_project
echo 'curl = "0.3.0"' >> Cargo.toml
```

Amusingly, you can install a third-party Cargo subcommand called [cargo-edit](https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit) using `cargo install` that makes it easier to modify your `Cargo.toml` file to add and remove dependencies!

```
cargo install cargo-edit
cargo add curl
cargo rm curl
```

---

An important thing to note is that **every** Cargo project manages and compiles a separate set of dependencies ([some background info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37472558/155423)). Thus it doesn't make sense to install a *compiled* library. The *source code* for each version of a library will be cached locally, avoiding downloading it multiple times.

See also:

- [cargo install <library_name> --library (Cargo issue #2552)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2552)
- [cargo-add documentation (added to Cargo directly in 1.62.0)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-add.html)

Comment: Seems like this does not actually fix the problem. The library is already listed as a dependency under Cargo.toml. When I try to build the project, it fails because the dependency is not installed. When I try to install the dependency, it fails due to the error in the original post.

Comment: @user5359531 - Try `cargo run`.