# How do I use char_width in rust?

Tags: rust

I am not able to install the crate corresponding to `char_width` ie. `wcwidth`. Seems like it has been taken down (according to [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/wcwidth)) but is still available for download.

Comment: According to crates.io, this crate is not very used. The most popular one seems to be [unicode-width](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-width).

Comment: Updating crates.io index
error: specified package `unicode-width v0.1.6` has no binaries
if you try to install it from the repo directly
Updating git repository `https://github.com/unicode-rs/unicode-width.git`
error: no packages found with binaries or examples,
I suppose the reason is repo doesn't contain the binaries

Comment: Do you want to use it as a program or as a library? If the latter then please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706999/error-installing-a-crate-via-cargo-specified-package-has-no-binaries

Comment: the above log is from cargo install

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your best bet is to [add as a dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) the [original repository](https://github.com/lucy/wcwidth.rs).

Otherwise, looks like the current behavior for crates.io is to continue providing the crate for users who already have it in their `Cargo.lock` file.  However, [cargo will refuse to add a yanked crate to the `Cargo.lock` file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html).  I'm guessing if you hand-edit a [version on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/wcwidth/versions) into your existing `Cargo.lock` it'll download it for you and will at least attempt to build it.