# How do I install the Rust crate in3?

Tags: rust, blockchain, ethereum, rust-cargo

When I run a program that uses this in3-rs crate I get an error.  I expect it to be installed because I followed the directions here: https://crates.io/crates/in3

I installed the Requirements described here: https://crates.io/crates/in3
I am using Ubuntu 18, cargo 1.49.0, and rustc 1.49.0.  I tried to install in3, in3-rs, in3-sys, and async-std each separately (with a sudo cargo install ). Each time I got a message saying "error: specified package... has no binaries"

I ran this command: `cargo install --list`

I saw this:

> ripgrep v12.1.1:

> ```
> rg
> ```

I tried using a variety of different Cargo.toml files.  But to install the ripgrep crate, I needed no Cargo.toml file.

I ran this command: `sudo cargo install in3`

But I saw this:

> [sudo] password for jdoe:
> Updating crates.io index error: specified package `in3 v0.1.7` has no binaries

A relevant version is returned in the output.  My Ubuntu server has access to the internet.  I have googled this problem, and I think that SO is where questions about Rust should be asked.

I tried the three suggestions for the content of the file for Cargo.toml that this [link](https://crates.io/crates/in3) has.

When my Cargo.toml file had this stanza `in3 = "0.1.7"`, the error was reproducible.

I had the same error when my Cargo.toml file had these two lines:

```
[dependencies]
in3 = "0.0.2"
```

The error was reproduced a third time when my Cargo.toml file had these three lines:

```
[dependencies]
async-std = "1.5.0"
in3 = "0.2.0"
```

To reproduce the problem, I ran "sudo cargo install in3"

I also tried to use `sudo cargo install` (without an argument to install) with the two Cargo.toml versions with the [dependencies] stanza.  But I got this error on those attempts:

> error: failed to parse manifest at `/opt/in3-3.1.2/rust/Cargo.toml`
>
> Caused by:   this virtual manifest specifies a [dependencies] section,
> which is not allowed

I tried using this as the Cargo.toml (and another version without the [dependencies] section):

```
[package]
name = "in3"
version = "0.2.0"
edition = '2018'

[dependencies]
async-std = "1.5.0"
in3 = "0.2.0"
```

I saw this:

> ```
> Updating crates.io index error: specified package `in3 v0.1.7` has no binaries
> ```

Update: I used "sudo cargo build" with this as my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "in3"
version = "0.1.7"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "in3"
path = "/home/jdoe/rust/contint.rs"

[dependencies]
async-std = "1.5.0"
in3 = "0.1.7"
```

It worked.  I then ran `sudo cargo run`, and it worked. But when I ran `sudo cargo install in3`, I got an error.

I ran this:    `cargo install --list`

But in3 is still not installed.  I ran a rust program, and it confirmed that in3 is not installed.

UPDATE (more recent): I ran `rustc foobar.rs`  But I saw this:

> error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `in3`?  -->
> foobar.rs:4:5   | 4 | use in3::eth1::*;   |     ^^^ maybe a missing
> crate `in3`?

How do I install the in3 crate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing a crate via cargo: specified package has no binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706999/error-installing-a-crate-via-cargo-specified-package-has-no-binaries) Don't use `cargo install` to add dependencies, you simply need to add it to your `Cargo.toml`. Your link to the `in3` crate shows an example of how to do that.

Comment: No, unfortunately my problem happens with different Cargo.toml values.  I updated my question to provide details of what happens.

Comment: If your `Cargo.toml` just has the `[dependencies]` section, then it is incomplete. You need a [`[package]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-package-section) section with `name`, `version`, and `edition`.

Comment: I tried a Cargo.toml version with name, version and edition.  It also failed with the same error.

Comment: As I said before, *don't use* `cargo install`. At this point you should just be able to use `cargo build` or `cargo run`.

Comment: I have made progress because of your comments.  Unfortunately, I cannot install in3 still. The "cargo build" and "cargo run" worked when I fixed the .toml file.  But in3 is still not installed.

Comment: Cargo libraries like `in3` aren't "installed". It won't show up in `cargo install --list`. If you were able to run `cargo build` with it listed as a dependency, then you can use it in your Rust code. What do you mean by "I ran a rust program, and it confirmed that in3 is not installed"?

Comment: I ran "rustc foobar.rs", and I saw the problem was that a statement referring to in3 caused a problem.  This comment can be deleted to keep the comments from being excessive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood package management with cargo.
Since `in3` is a library and not a binary crate, you cannot install it.

`cargo install` does not install dependencies like `npm install` or `pip install` does. `cargo install` will install binaries into your local filesystem (typically $HOME/.cargo/bin) for you to run.

Cargo will resolve dependencies for you when you `cargo run/check/build`. You do not need to install dependencies.

You may want to start a new folder structure and try the following:

1. Run `cargo init`. This will create a new binary package
2. Edit `Cargo.toml` and add the `in3` dependency and version.
3. Modify the `main.rs` file to use the `in3` library.
4. Run the program with `cargo run`. You will notice that cargo is resolving various dependencies while compiling your program.

For more info on Cargo, [here is the getting started guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/first-steps.html).