# Can Cargo download and build dependencies without also building the application?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to tell [Cargo](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html) to install and build all my dependencies, but not attempt to build my application?

I thought `cargo install` would do that, but it actually goes all the way to building my app too. I want to get to a state where `cargo build` would find all dependencies ready to use, but without touching the `/src` directory.

---

**What I'm really trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to build a Docker image for a Rust application, where I'd like to do the following steps:

Build time (`docker build .`):

1. import a docker image with rust tooling installed
2. add my Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files
3. download and build all dependencies
4. add my source directory to the image
5. build my source code

Run time (`docker run ...`):

1. run the application

I've tried the following `Dockerfile`, but the indicated step builds my application as well (which of course fails since the source directory isn't there yet):

```
FROM jimmycuadra/rust

ADD Cargo.toml /source
ADD Cargo.lock /source

RUN cargo install # <-- failure here

ADD src /source/src
RUN cargo build

ENTRYPOINT cargo run
```

The reason I want to separate the install dependencies step from actually building my application, is that if I don't change the dependencies, I want Docker to be able use a cached image with all dependencies already installed and built. Thus, I can't `ADD /src /source/src` until *after* installing the dependecies, as that would invalidate the cached image when I change my own code.

Comment: That's an interesting requirement! Have you tried to hack your way by providing a "fake" `lib.rs` that just lists the `extern crate`? It would probably create a `target` repository but you can always delete that after executing `cargo build`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! ;) Will try it when I get home. I'm completely new to Rust, so I don't know much about inner workings or what is required to make something build correctly - trial and error has been my approach so far...

Comment: I don't have much experience with Cargo myself, so it's more of a tentative work-around. For all I know there's exactly the command you want available already.

Comment: Is [`cargo vendor`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cargo-vendor) useful here?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: After struggling for quite some time with getting `cargo vendor` to install and run correctly on my image, I note that the deps are downloaded, but not built. I'm looking into if I can get them to precompile as well...

Answer (score 24):

There is no native support for building just the dependencies in Cargo, as far as I know. There is [an open issue for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2644). I wouldn't be surprised if you could submit something to Cargo to accomplish it though, or perhaps create a third-party Cargo addon. I've wanted this functionality for `cargo doc` as well, when my own code is too broken to compile ;-)

However, the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) that I maintain does accomplish your end goal. There's a [base Docker container](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/master/compiler/base/Dockerfile) that installs Rustup and copies in a [`Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/master/compiler/base/Cargo.toml) with all of the crates available for the playground. [The build steps create a blank project (with a dummy `src/lib.rs`), then calls `cargo build` and `cargo build --release` to compile the crates](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/dea331e1de3e22eb6fd6f6a1556df6c874700607/compiler/base/Dockerfile#L32-L39):

```
RUN cd / && \
    cargo new playground
WORKDIR /playground

ADD Cargo.toml /playground/Cargo.toml
RUN cargo build
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs
```

All of the downloaded crates are stored in the Docker image's `$HOME/.cargo` directory and all of the built crates are stored in the applications `target/{debug,release}` directories.

Later on, the real source files are copied into the container and `cargo build` / `cargo run` can be executed again, using the now-compiled crates.

If you were building an executable project, you'd want to copy in the Cargo.lock as well.

Comment: Generalized on libs/binaries, one could probably use the syntax `COPY Cargo.* ./`  (ADD works similarly as well, although is probably discouraged https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-2-the-difference-between-copy-and-add-in-a-dockerile )

Comment: Hi, Why `cargo build` and `cargo build --release` and not only the cargo build with release option?

Comment: @UselesssCat the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) allows you to compile your code in both debug and release modes, so we needed to precompile all the dependencies in both modes.

Answer (score 7):

If you add a dummy main or lib file, you can use `cargo build` to just pull down the dependencies. I'm currently using this solution for my Docker based project:

```
COPY Cargo.toml .
RUN mkdir src \
    && echo "// dummy file" > src/lib.rs \
    && cargo build
```

I'm using `--volumes`, so I'm done at this point. The host volumes come in and blow away the dummy file, and cargo uses the cached dependencies when I go to build the source later. This solution will work just as well if you want to add a `COPY` (or `ADD`) later and use the cached dependencies though.

Answer (score 5):

Based on a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2644#issuecomment-335272535)

```
FROM rust:1.37

WORKDIR /usr/src

# Create blank project
RUN USER=root cargo new PROJ

# We want dependencies cached, so copy those first.
COPY Cargo.toml /usr/src/PROJ/
COPY Cargo.lock /usr/src/PROJ/

WORKDIR /usr/src/PROJ

# This is a dummy build to get the dependencies cached.
RUN cargo build --release

# Now copy in the rest of the sources
COPY MyPROJECT/src /usr/src/PROJ/src/

# This is the actual build.
RUN cargo build --release \
    && mv target/release/appname /bin \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/PROJ

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 8888

CMD ["/bin/appname"]
```

Comment: this does not work if the project as a `test` section, like ```[[test]]
name = "it"
harness = false
``` since this depends on having valid tests... -.-'

Answer (score 5):

The [cargo-chef](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-chef) tool is designed to solve this problem. Here's an example from the README on how you can use it in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef as planner
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare  --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef as cacher
WORKDIR app
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM rust as builder
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
# Copy over the cached dependencies
COPY --from=cacher /app/target target
COPY --from=cacher $CARGO_HOME $CARGO_HOME
RUN cargo build --release --bin app

FROM rust as runtime
WORKDIR app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/app /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/app"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via `cargo init`, `cargo build`, and `cargo install`. For example, for a project called `foo`, define the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rust:slim-bullseye

# Build dependencies only.
RUN cargo init foo
COPY Cargo.toml foo/
RUN cargo build --release; \
    rm -rf foo

# Install `foo`.
COPY . .
RUN echo "// force Cargo cache invalidation" >> foo/src/main.rs; \
    cargo install --path foo

CMD ["foo"]
```

Here, `cargo init` creates the placeholder files that Cargo expects, `cargo build` builds the dependencies which were specified in the `Cargo.toml`, and `cargo install` creates the `foo` binary. For some reason, the Docker kept building the default project created by `cargo init foo`. This problem is resolved above by forcing an update for `main.rs` by appending `// force Cargo cache invalidation`.

To avoid slow builds due to large build contexts and large layers, make sure that unimportant folders such as `target` are ignored via `.dockerignore`. For example, define the following `.dockerignore`:

```
**/*.lock
LICENSE
README.md
target
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post this here so others will see it going forward.  There's an experimental tool for Docker I've just started using called cargo-wharf (https://github.com/denzp/cargo-wharf/tree/master/cargo-wharf-frontend).  It's a Docker BuildKit frontend that caches built cargo dependencies for you.  If you only change one of your source files, that's the only thing that gets rebuilt when you call `docker build`.    You use it by annotating your Cargo.toml file, then directing Docker to your Cargo.toml instead of a Dockerfile.  Go check it out, it's exactly what I wanted.  (I am in no way affiliated with the project.)