# How do I cache Rust crates locally when using Docker?

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

When using Cargo to build my Rust project, it downloads and compiles all the crates each time I trigger  `cargo build`.

Is there no way to cache these libraries and speedup my build process?

I am running this on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and using Docker to run my builds in. I guess there needs to be some mounted directory to share across builds which could solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide more details (system, configuration, a reproducible and minimal example). Cargo usually caches crate downloads globally and builds per project(crate); at least on the systems I have been working on.

Comment: Ok then. My builds are on dockers which must be causing the downloads again and again.

Comment: This sounds plausible. I have no experience with docker, though.

Comment: This is not an issue with Cargo, but Docker. You should provide the relevant bits of your `Dockerfile` for further context.

Comment: This question has some useful/relevant info which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130132/can-cargo-download-and-build-dependencies-without-also-building-the-application