# How do I fetch and compile only the dev-dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The Rust `Cargo.toml` specification file allows for [development dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#development-dependencies) section, e.g. `[dev-dependencies]`

*Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[dev-dependencies]
tempdir = "0.3"
```

What is the command to fetch and compile those development dependencies?

To be clear, I want to fetch and compile only the `[dev-dependencies]`. The [*Linked* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130132/can-cargo-download-and-build-dependencies-without-also-building-the-application?noredirect=1&lq=1) differs in that it regards fetching and compiling *all* dependencies and then building the application.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by only fetching/building the dev dependencies? I don't think it's possible to build *only* the dev dependencies, but you can make Cargo *also* build the dev dependencies by running `cargo build --tests`

Comment: @ShadowMitia a closely related question. [@ShepMaster answer](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2644) references open Issue [rust-lang #2644](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2644) that _is_ directly related this Question. Another answer mentions [`cargo-chef`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67257247/471376) which does not appear to have the capability I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I do not have enough reputation so I just answer.

As declare by your link and [rust-by-example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/dev_dependencies.html), it is impossible to "build" a binary from dev-dependencies.

> Sometimes there is a need to have dependencies for tests (or examples,
> or benchmarks) only. Such dependencies are added to Cargo.toml in the
> [dev-dependencies] section

To be sneaky, may be you can put some function under #[cfg(test)] and run `cargo test` so that your goal can be achieved.

A more appropriate way to selectively build by `cargo` using the feature flag, in cargo.toml and cargo command. You can take a look at the cargo command to toggle feature [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html) and [optional dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) which help control categorizing of features.

Comment: optional dependencies are not dev dependencies

Comment: Additionally, this answer seems to misunderstand the question as wanting to build a binary from the dependencies -- they are only wanting to build (maybe a better term would have been *compile*) the dev dependencies into their intermediate libraries.