# No matching package found (Docker + Rust)

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

I'm attempting to compile a Rust project in Docker and it's being frustrating. As far as I can tell it should be incredibly straightforward, but for some reason Docker can't find the Rust package.

Here's the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rust:1.6.1
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

Here's the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "project1_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
utility = { path = "./src/utility" }
iced = "0.6.0"
iced_native = "0.4"
iced_style = "0.5"
iced_core = "0.5"
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
webassembly = "0.8"
wry = "0.23.4"
```

And here's the output:

```
peterweyand@Peters-MacBook-Pro project1_1 % ./dockerrun.sh
2022/12/15 16:04:06 must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.351GB
Step 1/4 : FROM rust:1.6.1
manifest for rust:1.6.1 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/iced-rs/iced`
    Updating crates.io index
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `iced`
perhaps you meant:      cached
location searched: https://github.com/iced-rs/iced
required by package `project1_1 v0.1.0 (/)`
```

If instead of `FROM rust:1.6.1` I use `FROM rust:latest` then Docker hangs like this:

```
peterweyand@Peters-MacBook-Pro project1_1 % ./dockerrun.sh
2022/12/15 16:08:18 must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.351GB
Step 1/4 : FROM rust:latest
 ---> 7767cd0ef4e0
Step 2/4 : COPY . .
 ---> 356cfb7caed9
Step 3/4 : RUN cargo build --release
 ---> Running in 87dbc6c86df9
    Updating crates.io index
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what is going wrong?

EDIT: I usually suck at Docker because there are several ways of doing the same thing.

I tried this

```
FROM rust:1.66-alpine 
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .
RUN apk add alpine-sdk # This one is necessary for linking cc.
COPY ./src/backend/Cargo.toml ./src/backend/Cargo.lock ./
RUN cargo build --release
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

and it gave this output -

```
   Compiling libloading v0.7.4
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.5
   Compiling toml v0.5.10
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
   Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.66
   Compiling system-deps v6.0.3
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--version-script=/tmp/rustc2quFlR/list" "/tmp/rustc2quFlR/symbols.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.proc_macro_error_attr.1df7e329-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.2venke7z0qwetnto.rcgu.rmeta" "/target/release/deps/proc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.2bt08o7nuxqqfzig.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/target/release/deps" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/target/release/deps/libquote-a78ece94a3329b46.rlib" "/target/release/deps/libproc_macro2-3f4d87b0b9f5c5f5.rlib" "/target/release/deps/libunicode_ident-5c658c6e9005d30d.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libproc_macro-16667debc3013ce2.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd-19bcd24d54b4a32c.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libpanic_unwind-3814851f75d61802.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libobject-5007cbad366e7f54.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libmemchr-c7fe0e6a7e22626a.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libaddr2line-cdbb9a3725d71a8c.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libgimli-ad66f8ef705486ae.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_demangle-775cf8425902e89f.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd_detect-d09dc442a73afb02.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcfg_if-508c53ad79acc8ea.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libhashbrown-ac7c150ef5940f2b.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libminiz_oxide-d2c5dbbafb505b02.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libadler-fa394ecd0326b64a.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-d36cf05357e3b9d8.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libunwind-32953872cd386e07.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcfg_if-e844973f6e14767e.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liblibc-2f732132bffc407e.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liballoc-e0c40e7f51c7608f.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-3dc8593378fc4be9.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcore-d31b035ed558dec3.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcompiler_builtins-2b952fa9bf703518.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.66.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-o" "/target/release/deps/libproc_macro_error_attr-4660f50c1ee088e6.so" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-shared" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `proc-macro-error-attr` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `project1_1 v0.1.0 (/)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/target`
The command '/bin/sh -c cargo install --path .' returned a non-zero code: 101
Unable to find image 'my-rust-app:latest' locally
2022/12/15 17:31:02 must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my-rust-app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

And I also tried this -

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install protobuf-compiler openssl pkg-config libssl-dev rustc cmake cargo -y
RUN rustc -V
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

But still ran into problems compiling dependencies that relied on C.

So, my question at this point is "What is the easiest way of getting a rust program to run with a standard list of dependencies?" The hello world examples don't cut it for any Rust program that has a large crate stack.

Thanks.

Comment: Attempting to compile a rust 2021 crate with rust 1.6.1 (from 2016) will somewhat unsurprisingly lead to weird errors. You definitely want 1.61. And, it's probably not hanging, it just takes a long time. It can take 15 minutes if you have meh internet. You could check whether anything is being downloaded with tools like bandwhich or nload (Cargo isn't very nice on docker. You can lessen the pain with [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130132/can-cargo-download-and-build-dependencies-without-also-building-the-application/67257247#67257247), but it's still not fun.)

Comment: Yeah, it takes time to load and there's no verbose setting unfortunately. I'm starting over with a `FROM ubuntu:latest` but I'm now getting cmake errors.

Comment: (If you actually want help with those cmake errors, you need to post them, possibly as a separate question. Otherwise: good luck.)

Comment: You picked an absolute fun project to compile on docker. Try adding `RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev glib-dev atkmm-dev gtkmm3-dev openssl-dev openssl-libs-static webkit2gtk-dev libc-dev libsoup-dev` after `FROM`. That should be enough to at least compile the dependencies of `./Cargo.toml`. (I can't say anything about `src/{backend,utility}/Cargo.toml` since you don't show them, and your dockerfile is pretty weird (You overwrite `./Cargo.toml` with `src/backend/Cargo.toml` at some point?). If you still have problems, it would be nice if you could transform this into a self-contained example.)