# Is it okay to use a single shared directory as Cargo's target directory for all projects?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Cargo has the `--target-dir` flag which specifies a directory to store temporary or cached build artifacts. You also can set it user-wide in the `~/.cargo/config` file. I'd like to set it to single shared directory to make maintenance easier.

I saw some artifact directories are suffixed with some unique(?) hashes in the target-dir which looks safe, but the final products are not suffixed with hashes, which doesn't seem to be safe for name clashes. I'm not sure on this as I am not an expert on Cargo.

I tried setting `~/.cargo/config` to

```
[build]
target-dir = "./.build"
```

My original intention was to use the project's local `./.build` directory, but somehow Cargo places all build files into `~/.build` directory. I got curious what would happen I put all build files from every project into a single shared build directory.

It has worked well with several different projects so far, but working for a few samples doesn't mean it's designed or guaranteed to work with every case.

In my case, I am using **single shared build directory for all projects of all workspaces of a user**. Not only projects in a workspace. Literally every project in every workspace of a user. As far as I know, Cargo is designed to work with  a local `target` directory. If it is designed to work with only local directory, a shared build directory  is likely to cause some issues.

- Rust/Cargo 1.38.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "okay"? Did you try it?

Comment: @trentcl I meant "okay" as "intended/designed to work with no trouble". Sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: I tried to use single `~/.build` directory to build several project and it's working well so far. But working for a few cases doesn't mean it would work well for every cases. Therefore, I am asking for original design intention of this flag if used with single shared build directory.

Comment: If the goal is just to speed up compilation with cached build artifacts, [sccache](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache) would probably be a better option.

Comment: I'm with @apemanzilla on this one. You're trying to solve a problem with a false solution, and creating two more problems along the way. In particular, it will no longer be possible for you to build two projects with the same dependencies concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is intended to be safe.

I agree with the comments that there are probably better methods of achieving your goal. [Workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section) are a simple solution for a small group of crates, and [sccache](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache) is a more principled caching mechanism.

See also:

- [Fix running Cargo concurrently (PR #2486)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/2486)
- [Allow specifying a custom output directory (PR #1657)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/1657)
- [Can I prevent cargo from rebuilding libraries with every new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37471391/155423)

Comment: Why is sccache better? With a shared target directory I would expect any time any project tries to build a crate cargo checks if it's already in the target directory, and if it is then cargo does nothing. If using sccache instead, than cargo will think it does need to build, and start triggering a bunch of builds that will so happen to be very quickly satisfied by the cache, but I assume involve copying out of the cache and into your project specific target directory. That both sounds slower and like it would use more disk space. Is some part of this incorrect? Is it not ideal to just do both?

Comment: I got here because I am trying to understand: why isn't a single shared target folder the default? Unlike sccache it would require no user setup and it seems like it would be purely better.

Comment: @JosephGarvin as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669482/is-it-okay-to-use-a-single-shared-directory-as-cargos-target-directory-for-all/58880993#comment103646508_58669482), create project A and B that have dependency C, but use different target features for C. Then build A, B, A. Does A rebuild? Then try cleaning your target and build B, A, B. Then try cleaning and building A and B concurrently.

Comment: Ah, so a shared target directory is not smart enough to separate crates by feature flags? If it were, would the scenario still workout as I describe? I'm trying to understand if "try changing cargo to put a feature hash in the directory name" is the best way to go or if there is 0 perf advantage that would have over sccache (I suspect it would still avoid copying). The linked issue seems to be about it used to be the case that you couldn't run two cargo instances period.

Comment: How do I set `build.target-dir` on a workspace? Is that possible. I get no errors but also not the expected result.